# Keeping track of points in a grid

Tags: python, python-2.7, grid, point

Suppose we have an m times n rectangular room. The surface is covered with 1*1 tiles, meaning we have m*n number of square tiles. Every time a random point is given. The program is supposed to show the specific tile on which that point is placed. What is the simplest way to simulate the tiled surface?

First I wrote this:

```
room_coordinates = []
for m in range(m):
    for n in range(n):
        room_coordinates.append((m,n))
```

which only gives all the ordered pairs of natural numbers on the surface. Each tile is composed of four of such points, so I thought maybe I could use a dictionary like`{1: [(0,0), (1,0), (0,1), (1,1)]}` to denote a tile, but then again, I am not sure how I would  ascertain whether a point (0.5,0.5) is in fact within tile 1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would represent each tile by its bottom leftmost coordinate and that way you can know where a point lies by taking its floor function. i.e

```
x= math.floor(x)
```

in the case of the point (0.5,0.5) you could take the floor function to get (0,0) and use your mapping to give tile 1

an advantage of this is it does not require you to store all four points of the tile.
A disadvantage is you would have to decided a rule on what happens if a point lies on an edge.